# Why might my A/C condenser have 2 circuit breakers near each other, in series?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

(My house is in Texas, built in 2001.)
Today I was outside inspecting my electricals, and I noticed that my A/C unit has 2 breakers associated with it:

1. 60A breaker in the primary breaker box
2. 40A breaker in a smaller box directly behind the A/C compressor / heat-exchanger, maybe 10 feet away from the first one.

Out of curiosity, I confirmed that the breaker in the primary box does shut down the compressor & heat-exchanger fan.

I have to assume that these 2 breakers are wired in series, with respect to each other.  Why might it have been done this way?

Comment: Having one at the unit allows a repair person to definitively shut it off under their control. Not uncommon.

Comment: Is the box by the AC capable of being used as a small subpanel with the addition of more breakers?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The breaker in your main panel is required to protect the wiring going out of the panel.

Large appliances like air conditioners are required to have a disconnect within sight so maintainers can positively switch off power while servicing them. Lock-out devices on the main breaker are also acceptable, but obscure. Generally unfused disconnects are used for the local disconnect (since the overcurrent protection is provided by the breaker in the panel), but perhaps your installer had this handy and it was quicker to install this than to run to a warehouse and pick up an unfused disconnect.

There is no safety downside to this arrangement, you are definitely protected from overloads. The one minor downside is that if you do ever have an overload, either or both breakers might trip, so in that even you may have to check (and reset) both.

Comment: Code reference is NEC 2022 440.14 Location - "Disconnecting means shall be located within sight from, and readily accessible from the air-conditioning or refrigerating equipment."

Comment: The unit probably has a maximum OCPD requirement, or the breaker panel did not have listed breakers for the hvac equipment.

Answer (score 3):

Actually if your outside unit is “within sight” of the breaker panel the installer did not know that a 4 dollar lock out tab can be added to the panel and create a 100% code compliant disconnect that can be locked. Code requires a lockable disconnect within sight on a ground level this is 50’. Many HVAC installers only know a small portion of code and don’t realize that a breaker lock is ok and install the cheesy disconnects in most cases.

Comment: In 2001 they were in line of sight (and 10 feet apart).  Today there is a picket fence between them, so now it is perhaps more appropriate that they did it this way.  (And consequently, I just learned that I didn't accidentally violate electrical code by adding the fence.)

Comment: Talk about "Law of Unintended Consequences" that building a simple fence could create an electrical code violation!